# Quickbooks Desktop Integration Exits without Starting on Different Computer

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have a simple program that is supposed to integrate some Excel functions and Quickbooks on the computer, not over the internet. My program works on the original computer it was programmed on. However, when I try to run the application on a fresh computer with only QuickBooks and Office Suite products installed, the program starts, but when the code runs, the code exits and nothing happens. All of the Excel functions work, but the QuickBooks area does not. The relevant QuickBooks section is written in C#:

```
    // Create the session manager object using QBFC
    string QBSource = /*UserInput*/;
    QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
    bool booSessionBegun = false;
    try
    {
        // Open the connection and begin a session to QuickBooks
        sessionManager.OpenConnection("ExcelToQbConnection", "Excel-to-QB Connection");
        sessionManager.BeginSession(QBSource, ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
        booSessionBegun = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + "\nStack Trace: \n" + ex.StackTrace + "\nExiting the application");
        if (booSessionBegun)
        {
            sessionManager.EndSession();
            sessionManager.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out why the code runs and then exits at this stage without an error. I've tried including Interop.QBFC13.dll (the dependency file) in the exported file, and I've tried leaving it not in the file for it to use the one in registry. I've tried using an installer to double check dependencies (although I honestly may have done it wrong). QBCF Monitor Service, QBIDPService, and Quickbooks Desktop are all running. When troubleshooting, I installed .Net 3.5, but my program still isn't working.

I've also tried running other QuickBooks integrations. They also don't run, so I figure it is something on the QuickBooks side, but I can't find anything on how to fix this.

Is there something else I can test to see if that is it?